# spring2 annotation has not rendered

Tags: spring, annotations

I am new to startup a Java with Spring 2.5.5 project. But have some problem that the Spring annotation has not been resolved. I means my JSP shows the spring annotation directly, like this: 
  ${msg}

[ \target\pom.xml ]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.demo.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorldSpringWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>HelloWorldSpringWeb Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.6</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>2.5.6</spring.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>        
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>       

    </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>HelloWorldSpringWeb</finalName>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.11.v20150529</version>
            <configuration>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/spring2</contextPath>
                </webApp>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <wtpContextName>spring2</wtpContextName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>    
  </build>
</project>
```

[ \WEB-INF\web.xml ]

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

[ \WEB-INF\mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml ]

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <bean name="/welcome.htm" 
        class="com.demo.spring.HelloWorldController" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.demo.spring" />

</beans>
```

[ com.demo.spring.HelloWorldController.java ]

```
package com.demo.spring;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        model.addObject("msg", "hello world");

        return model;
    }

}
```

[ \WEB-INF\pages\index.jsp ]

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Hello World!!!</h2>
  <h2>${msg}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

To access the controller, use this URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/HelloWorldSpringWeb/welcome.htm
```

Finally, output on web browser like this:

```
Hello World!!!
${msg}
```

As you see, ${msg} is not rendered. What's wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Starting a project with Spring 2.5.6 is a nonsense. This version is very, very old (9 years!), and not maintained anymore. Use the latest stable Spring version. And do the same for everything else: Java 6 -> Java 8, servlet 2.5 -> servlet 3.1, junit 3.8 -> junit 4.x.

Comment: I have to maintain an old project which is using this version of Spring so that I want to learn about it.

Answer (score 0):

After my investigation, I should correct my question to: "Spring 2.5.6 EL has not been resolved".

And now I know that I can add this statement on every pages those has EL expression inside:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
```

Yes it can solve my problem. But I don't want to add this statement in too many pages in my project.

I find that it is caused by isELIgnored is default to "true" if web.xml is equal or lower than version 2.3. So that I need to add this code to set isELIgnored to true globally:

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-ignored>false</el-ignored>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

But no luck. The EL is still hasn't been resolved.

Someone can help?

Thanks a lot.